# Rake always segfaults and core dumps, even when successful

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rake, segmentation-fault

I have a VPS running 64-bit Debian Lenny, and I'm deploying a couple of Rails 3 apps.

I have no problem locally, but whenever Rake is run from the command line (or capistrano) Rake segfaults, and core dumps... even though Rake seems to complete **successfully** in most cases!

I have spent weeks trying to fix this, tried installing REE, 1.8.7, 1.9.2-p180 & 1.9.2-p290... All of them fail.

I'm unsure how to get any meaningful information from the core dumps... and all my searches on Google have been fruitless.

What options are there to stop this from happening? 
And is there a way to stop the core dumps from consuming all my disk space?!

```
[BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-linux]

-- control frame ----------
---------------------------

-- C level backtrace information -------------------------------------------
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_vm_bugreport+0x5f)[0x2afdf1ff2b7f]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9 [0x2afdf1ecf81c]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9(rb_bug+0xb3) [0x2afdf1ecf993]
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/libruby.so.1.9 [0x2afdf1f81b8c]
/lib/libpthread.so.0 [0x2afdf22aba80]
/lib/libselinux.so.1 [0x2aaab7d3531d]
/lib/libselinux.so.1 [0x2aaab7d2857f]

[NOTE]
You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
Bug reports are welcome.
For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html

Aborted (core dumped)

Exiting via interrupt: 2
```

EDIT: coredump analysis yields:

```
sudo gdb /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby core.5654
#0 rb_vm_get_sourceline (cfp=<value optimized out>) at vm.c:696
#1 0x00002ba7e901697c in rb_bug (fmt=0x1e4d0540 "�\026�\036") at error.c:246
#2 0x00002ba7e90c8b8c in sigsegv (sig=<value optimized out>, info=<value optimized out>, ctx=<value optimized out>) at signal.c:613
#3 <signal handler called> #4 0x00002aaab7d3531d in ?? () from /lib/libselinux.so.1
#5 0x00002aaab7d2857f in ?? () from /lib/libselinux.so.1
#6 0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

Answer (score 1):

> I'm unsure how to get any meaningful information from the core dumps...

Have you tried the *standard* way of getting info from core dumps?

```
gdb /path/to/executable /path/to/core
(gdb) where
```

Comment: A command like this to run gdb right?
`sudo gdb /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby core.5654`


`#0  rb_vm_get_sourceline (cfp=<value optimized out>) at vm.c:696`


`#1  0x00002ba7e901697c in rb_bug (fmt=0x1e4d0540 "�\026�\036") at error.c:246`


`#2  0x00002ba7e90c8b8c in sigsegv (sig=<value optimized out>, info=<value optimized out>, ctx=<value optimized out>) at signal.c:613`        


`#3  <signal handler called>`


`#4  0x00002aaab7d3531d in ?? () from /lib/libselinux.so.1`


`#5  0x00002aaab7d2857f in ?? () from /lib/libselinux.so.1`


`#6  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()`

Comment: (Sorry don't know how to get code blocks in comments)

What can you do with this information though? It doesn't seem to say anything meaningful, other than indicating the error is occurring somewhere in libselinux.so.1?

Comment: I've edited the question and added your stack trace. Yes, it would appear that the problem is a bug in SELinux, and has little to do with ruby. Installing libselinux-dbg (or some such) package containing debug symbols for libselinux.so.1 may give further clues.